# Large number received when trying to do simple float division

Tags: c++

```
float taxednumber = number  * (float)(20/100.0);
taxednumber = number - taxednumber;`
```

If the number input is 135 I receive taxednumber as 1966805346. Why is it becoming such a large number? I have tried many different types of division to fix this problem and after trying most this is my final result. Troubleshooting the numbers just showed me the values being normal as far as I saw, so the problem must occur in the calculation.

EDIT: The compiler I am using is GNU GCC within Codeblocks

Comment: Have you tried `float taxednumber = (20*number)/100.0;` ?

Comment: Please post a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In what platform are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: Here's an example of a minimal code sample that attempts to illustrate "the problem": http://ideone.com/jqNI8v.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the data type of number.  If you are using floating point, use floating point ... 20 is an integer, 20.0 is floating point.  If number is not a float, it will cause issues with both lines of code shown.

Edit: since the OP said he was using gcc, I wrote a little code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   int number = 135;
   float taxednumber = number * (float)(20/100.0);

   printf("number: %d\n", number);
   printf("taxednumber: %f\n", taxednumber);
   printf("int calc: %d\n", 20/100.0);
   printf("float calc: %f\n", (float)(20/100.0));  
   printf("float with cast calc: %f\n", (float)((float)20/100.0));  
}
```

**Output:**

```
number: 135
taxednumber: 27.000000
int calc: -1717986918
float calc: 0.200000
float with cast calc: 0.200000
```

There is little information with the original question, it could be as simple that the OP is printing the value with the wrong output format (see the "int calc" line).

Environment used: gcc on VirtualBox using Ubunto.

Comment: The data type of number is int while taxednumber is a float. I have switched them around and changing number from int to float and vice versa changes nothing while changing the data type of taxednumber from float to int and int to float makes the number produced fluctuate wildly, going to 2.37137e+032

Comment: It is an int, not a pointer to an int, or some other wacky thing?  Just checking.

Comment: Yes an int, nothing wacky.

Comment: I'm trying to get the code in that form but when I try to recreate it, the number comes up as wanted. I don't want to post all of the code into here, as I feel it would be too long.

Comment: @user3713800 Exactly, because the code you show doesn't do what you think it does. So people who know stuff don't answer, and you are left with answers that are speculative and completely wrong.

Comment: @user3713800 Please see my updated answer.  Are you "seeing" the wrong value in a debugger or through something like a printf?  The problem could be with how you are seeing the value, not with the value itself.  It would be helpful to learn how to shrink code code into snippets, it is hard to guess, and then anyone kind enough to give it a shot ends up with nasty comments and downvotes.

Comment: @sharth You are correct.  I fixed/ran this and edited my response, though it doesn't really affect the answer (wrong printf format) if my guess is correct about the source of the problem.